# Node.js website not deploying in Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, windows, azure, azure-web-app-service

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
I just want to host this `Node.js` application on an Azure Web App. 
I have tried with many ways but it is not working, how can I solve this.

After checking the log it is showing this error

```
Detailed Error Information:
Module     DirectoryListingModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x00000000
Requested URL      http://livehoah:80/
Physical Path      D:\home\site\wwwroot
Logon Method       Anonymous
Logon User     Anonymous
```

This is the configuration file

```
<!-- 
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->


<configuration>
    <system.webServer>


        <handlers>
            <!-- indicates that the app.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- Don't interfere with requests for logs -->
                <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$" />
                </rule>

                <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>

                <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options -->
        <!--<iisnode      
          node_env="%node_env%"
          nodeProcessCommandLine="&quot;%programfiles%\nodejs\node.exe&quot;"
          nodeProcessCountPerApplication="1"
          maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
          maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="3"
          namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="2000"      
          maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
          maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
          asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
          initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
          maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
          watchedFiles="*.js"
          uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"      
          gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
          loggingEnabled="true"
          logDirectoryNameSuffix="logs"
          debuggingEnabled="true"
          debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
          debuggerPathSegment="debug"
          maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
          appendToExistingLog="false"
          logFileFlushInterval="5000"
          devErrorsEnabled="true"
          flushResponse="false"      
          enableXFF="false"
          promoteServerVars=""
         />-->

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the dependency issue, I got that in log file.